# One argument, multiple paragraphs?

Tags: paragraphs, mla

How do I structurally split up an argument into multiple paragraphs? Let's say I'm using two texts as evidence for one argument, and I want to devote one paragraph to each text.

What would the introductory and concluding sentences of my body paragraphs look like? How would I connect the first paragraph to the second?

Note: I need to follow MLA 7 format, if that makes a difference.

Comment: This is completely off topic. Try [writers.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for writing advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else stumbles across this problem, this is what I ended up doing:

> [State the argument in relation to text A].
>   [Paragraph 1]
>
> Similarly to [Text A], [State the argument in relation to text B].
>   [Paragraph 2]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I would do it:

> [1] I argue that . [2] In what follows, I defend this claim by looking at two texts, text A and text B. [3] From text A, we will see how ~ is used to structure ~. [4] Text B further supports and enhances this point by ~.

Then make your argument from A, "I begin by showing how this appears in A". Then make your argument from B with a sentence "I now turn to ... ". Then articulate how you felt both supported your point.

Depending on your discipline, the use of *I* may not be preferred.

Comment: Well, it's a formal essay so personal nouns are not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen a lots of video on arguments essay writing. Here you can keep your essay in 4 paragraph. In first paragraph you can write introduction and your choice of what you want to argue.

In second paragraph, you can mention your point of view for your choice.

In third paragraph, you can mention your another point of view for your choice.

fourth paragraph will be a concluding paragraph.

So, you can go and connect with these paragraph with cohesion and coherence. Hopefully your task will be appreciated.